# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to insert values into my comments table and I am getting a error. Its saying that I can not add or update child row and I have no idea what that means.
My schema looks something like this:

```
--
-- Baza danych: `koxu1996_test`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Struktura tabeli dla tabeli `user`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
  `id` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `password_real` char(32) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `code` char(8) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `activated` enum('0','1') COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `activation_key` char(32) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `reset_key` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `street` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `house_number` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `apartment_number` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `zip_code` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `phone_number` varchar(16) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `country` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `province` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `pesel` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `register_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `authorised_time` datetime NOT NULL,
  `edit_time` datetime NOT NULL,
  `saldo` decimal(9,2) NOT NULL,
  `referer_id` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `level` int(8) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `country` (`country`),
  KEY `province` (`province`),
  KEY `referer_id` (`referer_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=83 ;
```

and the mysql statement I am trying to do looks something like this:

```
INSERT INTO `user` (`password`, `code`, `activation_key`, `reset_key`, `register_time`,                `edit_time`, `saldo`, `referer_id`, `level`) VALUES (:yp0, :yp1, :yp2, :yp3, NOW(), NOW(), :yp4, :yp5, :yp6). Bound with :yp0='fa1269ea0d8c8723b5734305e48f7d46', :yp1='F154', :yp2='adc53c85bb2982e4b719470d3c247973', :yp3='', :yp4='0', :yp5=0, :yp6=1
```

the error I get looks like this:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`koxu1996_test`.`user`, CONSTRAINT `user_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`country`) REFERENCES `country_type` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON
>   UPDATE NO ACTION)

Comment: Did you look at any of the similar question/answers here of SO before posting? Your error message clearly tells you that the `koxu1996_test.country` value you are(are not) inserting is not a valid value from `country_type.id`.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It just simply means that the value for column country on table comments you are inserting doesn't exist on table **country_type** or you are not inserting value for country on table **user**. 
Bear in mind that the values of column country on table comments is dependent on the values of ID on table **country_type**.

Answer (score 6):

You have foreign keys between this table and another table and that new row would violate that constraint.

You should be able to see the constraint if you run `show create table user`, it shows up as `CONSTRAINT...` and it shows what columns reference what tables/columns.

In this case `country` references `country_type (id)` and you are not specifying the value of `country`. You need to put a value that exists in `country_type`.

Answer (score 2):

Just to throw in my own issue in case it can help someone else, I was copy/pasting entries in my migration files and messed up by putting quotes around an integer. Since the value I was trying to enter was considered a string going into an integer field that was referencing another integer, this error came up.

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be thath your primary key in source table IS NOT unsigned, so I solved same insert with (notice `id` int(8) unsigned):

> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (   `id` int(8) unsigned NOT NULL
>   AUTO_INCREMENT,   `username` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
>   `password` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,   `password_real`
>   char(32) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,   `email` varchar(32) COLLATE
>   utf8_bin NOT NULL,   `code` char(8) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
>   `activated` enum('0','1') COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
>   `activation_key` char(32) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,   `reset_key`
>   varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,   `name` varchar(32) COLLATE
>   utf8_bin NOT NULL,   `street` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
>   `house_number` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
>   `apartment_number` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,   `city`
>   varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,   `zip_code` varchar(32)
>   COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,   `phone_number` varchar(16) COLLATE
>   utf8_bin NOT NULL,   `country` int(8) NOT NULL,   `province` int(8)
>   NOT NULL,   `pesel` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
>   `register_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
>   `authorised_time` datetime NOT NULL,   `edit_time` datetime NOT NULL, 
>   `saldo` decimal(9,2) NOT NULL,   `referer_id` int(8) NOT NULL,
>   `level` int(8) NOT NULL,   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),   KEY `country`
>   (`country`),   KEY `province` (`province`),   KEY `referer_id`
>   (`referer_id`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin
>   AUTO_INCREMENT=83 ;

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the value was empty for target table column while the reference table column has it. hence was throwing this error.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the references values does not corresponding on the related table. Just be sure the values exist on reference table and currents rows has corresponding valid values.

Answer (score 1):

In my case , its no problem in **SQL** commands , but the inputs was not sending as  **$request** , so in php.ini file :

max_input_vars was 1000 by default and I changed it to :

```
max_input_vars = 2000
```

then you have to restart web server .

Comment: Why minus score ? , this is a **Real Solution** and really solved my problem . Some errors are side effect of another errors or incorrect configurations.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass `NULL` for empty values. Not empty string such as `''`

Answer (score 0):

in my case this was the error:
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'brand_name_ur' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `brands` (`brand_name_en`, `brand_name_ur`, `brand_slug_en`, `brand_slug_ur`, `brand_image`) values (SAMI, ?, sami, سامی, upload/brand/1742772943246486.png))

and fixed by

'brand_name_ur' => $request -> brand_image_ur,
< changing brand_image_ur to brand_name_ur. Noob mistak. took my hour.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @Tsimtsum
By running a request like :

```sql
SELECT user.id as user_id, country as user_country_type_id, country_type.id as country_type_id
FROM `user`
LEFT JOIN country_type ON country_type.id = user.country
WHERE country_type.id is null;
```

it probably returns some rows and it should not !

You can delete it (probably a bad idea if you are in production) using request like :

```sql
DELETE user
FROM `user`
LEFT JOIN country_type ON country_type.id = user.country
WHERE country_type.id is null;
```

and adding constraint should be done after !

Answer (score 0):

add to your migrations

```
$this->addSql('SET foreign_key_checks = 0');
.....
$this->addSql('SET foreign_key_checks = 1');
```

Comment: please add more details to your answer, it helps to understand the solution better