# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation error when inserting date to a table in Laravel 5

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I'am trying to insert a date to a table but I got this message:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   ('stagesite'.'internships', CONSTRAINT
>   'internships_contact_id_foreign' FOREIGN KEY

This is my code:

```
public function store( Request $request) 
{ 
    $input = $request->all(); 
    $input['status_id'] = 1; 
    internship::create($input); 
    dd(' success '); 
}
```

And that's my form:

```
<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('contact') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
    {{ form :: select('course_id',$courses , null , ['id' => 'course_id', 'class' =>'form-control'] ) }} 
</div> 
<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('contact') ? 'has-error' : '' }}"> 
    {{ form :: hidden('contact_id',$contacts , null , ['id' => 'contact_id', 'class' =>'form-control'] ) }} 
</div>
```

Comment: public function store( Request $request)
    {
        $input = $request->all();
        $input['status_id'] = 1;
        internship::create($input);

        dd(' success ');
    }

Comment: and that is my form <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('contact') ? 'has-error' : ''  }}">
                                {{ form :: select('course_id',$courses , null , ['id' => 'course_id', 'class' =>'form-control'] ) }}
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('contact') ? 'has-error' : ''  }}">
                                {{ form :: hidden('contact_id',$contacts , null , ['id' => 'contact_id', 'class' =>'form-control'] ) }}


                            </div>

Comment: Edit your question and update your code there.

Comment: Duplicate: check this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17648179/sqlstate23000-integrity-constraint-violation-1452-cannot-add-or-update-a-chi)

Comment: First make sure that you have added the 'contact_id' into $fillable on `internship` model. Then check the value of `$contacts` variable on your form

Answer (score 0):

First of all See your error before asking help.

You have set foreign key relationship in Database. And When you are trying to insert data, Relation is not match with foreign key and you are getting this error.

You must take care of foreign key relation and must insert same data as in relation with other table.

You can get more idea about relationship with laravel by [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships).

you can also get more idea how to insert data through Laravel controller by [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent).